# How can I remove a stuck pivot rod from a popup sink drain?

Tags: bathroom, sink

I cannot get the pivot rod out to remove my bathroom sink stopper assembly. I unscrewed the nut easily enough. The ball part doesn't seem stuck but the rod will not come out. Every post/youtube video/instruction makes it seem like it will easily slide out once the nut is removed. I sprayed it with WD40 and will try again in a bit, but any ideas otherwise?

update: the WD40 worked! Now if I could get the dumb J trap loose!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works. (Answers don't go in your question, and you need to accept an answer to resolve the question.)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the ball /pivot plugged up with hair and toothpaste more than once. I usually use a pair of pliers and a little force to remove it, in one case I had to remove the drain and use a long handled screwdriver to pry it out from the inside, once it was clean it slid back in place no problem. So give it a bit of force and it will come out.